# Reset nested array in react-hook-form

Tags: react-hook-form

I try to reset a nested array in react hook form without success
I created the following sandbox
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-reset-usefieldarray-forked-zp3ub?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: can you add a little more detail how you are trying to reset and how it is not working, also it would be helpful if you can add code in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be fixed by following the nested `useFieldArray` example [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-nested-arrays-x7btr). That example is created by the library's author. I have no idea why it happens though, it may be a library bug or a quirk because the author never expects you to write code that way..

Basically you need to refactor your code by putting the nested fields in a child component instead of placing everything in one big component. So change this:

```js
const { fields, remove } = useFieldArray({
  control,
  name: "names"
});

const { fields: nested } = useFieldArray({
  control,
  name: "names[0].nested"
});
```

```js
<ul>
  {fields.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={item.id}>
        <input
          name={`names[${index}].firstName`}
          defaultValue={`${item.firstName}`}
          ref={register()}
        />
        <ul>
          {nested.map((nestedItem, nestedIndex) => {
            return (
              <li key={item.id}>
                <input
                  name={`names[${index}].nested[${nestedIndex}].lastName`}
                  defaultValue={`${nestedItem.lastName}`}
                  ref={register()}
                />
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

To something like this:

#### Parent

```js
const { fields, remove } = useFieldArray({
  control,
  name: "names"
});
```

```js
<ul>
  {fields.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={item.id}>
        <input
          name={`names[${index}].firstName`}
          defaultValue={`${item.firstName}`}
          ref={register()}
        />
        <NestedArray
          index={index}
          control={control}
          register={register}
        />
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

#### NestedArray

```js
const { fields, remove } = useFieldArray({
  control,
  name: "names[0].nested"
});

return (
  <ul>
    {fields.map((nestedItem, nestedIndex) => {
      return (
        <li key={nestedItem.id}>
          <input
            name={`names[${index}].nested[${nestedIndex}].lastName`}
            defaultValue={`${nestedItem.lastName}`}
            ref={register()}
          />
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit React Hook Form Reset useFieldArray (forked)]